# Flutter - sharedpreferences saving state within a ListView

Tags: flutter

I have this switch that is inside a ListView.builder. I change the switch to turn notification on and off. The problem is that when I change a switch after restarting the app everyone stays the same as I changed

```
bool isSwitched = false;
  String keyNameOne = "key";
  Future<bool> loadDataOne() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getBool(keyNameOne) ?? false;
  }
  Future<bool> saveDataOne() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.setBool(keyNameOne, isSwitched);
    
  }

  setData() async {
    loadDataOne().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        isSwitched = value;
      });
    });
  }

Switch(
        value: isSwitched,
        activeColor: Colors.pink,
        activeTrackColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
        onChanged: (value) async {
          setState(() {
            isSwitched = value;
            saveDataOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could give you an idea.

```
Future<void> saveDataOne(value) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.setBool(keyNameOne, value);
    setState(() { isSwitched = value; })
}
```

and in `onChanged`

```
onChanged: (value) {
              saveDataOne(value);
           }
```

Hope that works!

Comment: The problem persists. Nothing has changed about the problem